# Copy a column value from another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

Let us say I have two dataframes: `df1 and df2`. Assume the following initial values.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['ASX-112','YTR-789','ASX-124','UYT-908','TYE=456','ERW-234','UUI-675','GHV-805','NMB-653','WSX-123'],
'Costperlb':[4515,5856,3313,9909,8980,9088,6765,3456,9012,1237]})
df2=df1[df1['Costperlb']>4560]
```

As you can see, df2 is a proper subset of df1 (it was created from df1 by imposing a condition on selection of rows).

I added a column to df2, which contains certain values based on a calculation. Let us call this df2['grade'].

```
df2['grade']=[1,4,3,5,1,1]
```

df1 and df2 contain one column named 'ID' which is guaranteed to be unique in each dataframe.

I want to:

1. Create a new column in df1 and initialize it to 0. Easy. `df1['grade']=0`.
2. Copy df2['grade'] values over to df1['grade'], ensuring that `df1['ID']=df2['ID']` for each such copy.

The result should be the grade values for the corresponding IDs copied over.

Step 2 is what is perplexing me a bit. A naive `df1['grade']=df2['grade'].values` does not work obviously as the lengths of the two dataframes is different.

Now, if I think hard enough, I could possibly come up with a monstrosity like:

`df1['grade'].loc[(df1['ID'].isin(df2)) & ...]` but I am uncomfortable with doing that.

I am a newbie with python, and furthermore, the indices of df1 are being used elsewhere after this assignment, and I do not want drop indices, reset indices as some of the solutions are suggested in some of the search results I found.

I just want to find out rows in df1 where the 'ID' row matches the 'ID' row in df2, and then copy the 'grade' column value in that specific row over. How do I do this?

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['ASX-112','YTR-789','ASX-124','UYT-908','TYE=456','ERW-234','UUI-675','GHV-805','NMB-653','WSX-123'],
'Costperlb':[4515,5856,3313,9909,8980,9088,6765,3456,9012,1237]})
df2=df1[df1['Costperlb']>4560]
df2['grade']=[1,4,3,5,1,1]
```

You can use merge with "left". In this way the indexing of df1 is preserved:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2[["ID","grade"]], on="ID", how="left")
new_df["grade"] = new_df["grade"].fillna(0)
new_df
```

Output:

```
    ID   Costperlb grade
0   ASX-112 4515    0.0
1   YTR-789 5856    1.0
2   ASX-124 3313    0.0
3   UYT-908 9909    4.0
4   TYE=456 8980    3.0
5   ERW-234 9088    5.0
6   UUI-675 6765    1.0
7   GHV-805 3456    0.0
8   NMB-653 9012    1.0
9   WSX-123 1237    0.0
```

Here I called the merged dataframe new_df, but you can simply change it to df1.

**EDIT**

If instead of 0 you want to replace the NaN with a string, try this:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2[["ID","grade"]], on="ID", how="left")
new_df["grade"] = new_df["grade"].fillna("No transaction possible")
new_df
```

Output:

```
    ID    Costperlb       grade
0   ASX-112 4515    No transaction possible
1   YTR-789 5856    1
2   ASX-124 3313    No transaction possible
3   UYT-908 9909    4
4   TYE=456 8980    3
5   ERW-234 9088    5
6   UUI-675 6765    1
7   GHV-805 3456    No transaction possible
8   NMB-653 9012    1
9   WSX-123 1237    No transaction possible
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that new_df is ordered in terms of indices the same as df1 is, correct? The reason I ask is that df1 itself was created in the calling function through a sorting on another column, so the indices are not sequential, and for later processing, that matters. Also, why use .astype("str") above? Just curious.

Comment: Yes the new_df has the same index as df1! You can just rename new_df with df1 actually. This is because in the merging the option "left" assures that the main table to join on is df1. `.astype("str")` can be removed, I was using it because first  I tried with `join` and it was giving me an error related to the object type of ID column. I will remove it from the code above, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: One question: what if I want to prepopulate the merged column in df1 with a certain value before I do the merge? If do that, I end up with new columns with _x, etc. If I don't, I end up with NaN's. I can't seem to find a way to replace those NaNs afterwards. fillna('No transaction possible') etc. don't work.

Comment: It is weird, for me fillna("no transaction") works perfectly (see updated answer). Which error do you get when you try it?